# importing a screen from the same JS file

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have consulted every question in StackOverflow regarding this problem with no success. I continuously get the following error `Route 'Home' should declare a screen. [image: Android Emulator Error]

This error seems to indicate that I must import a component into my working file if I want to use it as a screen, is that the case? If so, Why? That's probably what's wrong with my code, otherwise, I'm not sure what is wrong here: I would like to understand why this isn't working, I have consulted multiple guides on the subject.

my `index.android.js`:

```
import './app/index.js'
```

my `index.js` (not in full):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, TextInput } 
from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const RallyMobileNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: RallyMobile },
  LogIn: { screen: LogIn }
  },{
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
});

class RallyMobile extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Welcome',
  };
  state = {
  initialPosition: {},
  lastPosition: {},
  userData: [],
  }

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('LogIn')}
          title='Sign In'
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.EventListContainer}>
        <EventList
          location={this.state.lastPosition.location ?
          this.state.lastPosition.location : 
          this.state.initialPosition.location}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
    );
  };
};

class LogIn extends Component {
  state = {
    userName: '',
    password: ''
  }
   static navigationOptions = {
     title: 'Sign In',
   };
   logInUser = () => {
     console.log("test");
   }

   render() {
     return(
       <View>
       <View style={{padding: 10}}>
         <TextInput
           style={{height: 40}}
           placeholder="Username"
           onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userName})}
         />
         <TextInput
            style={{height: 40}}
            placeholder="Password"
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password})}
         />
        </View>
        <View>
          <button
            onPress={logInUser()}
            title='Sign In'
          />
        </View>
     </View>
     )
   }
 }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RallyMobile', () => RallyMobileNavigator);
```

Comment: Update: I stepped through stackNavigator.js in the Chrome debugger and found that the screen property of `routeConfigMap.Home` is undefined but I still don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
const RallyMobileNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: RallyMobile },
  LogIn: { screen: LogIn }
  },{
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
});
```

To just above

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('RallyMobile', () => RallyMobileNavigator);
```

Credit:
https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/571#issuecomment-284207331

Comment: Thank you so much, That fixed it, Does that fix it because the components have to be defined before they can be used by the navigator?

Comment: I don't really see a way for me to solve this question out, maybe I don't have enough notability? The only way I see is to answer my own question, but that wouldn't give you due credit.